# How to create a handler that returns a tuple using MediatR;

Tags: c#, handler, mediatr

I Have the following handler using mediator pattern but I like to return different data than what it currently returning,

```
public class GetSampleByStatusCommand : IRequest<SampleListCriteria>
{
    public SampleListCriteria SampleListCriteria { get; set; }
}
```

my handler,

```
public class GetSampleByStatusHandler : IRequestHandler<GetSampleByStatusCommand, SampleListCriteria>
{
    private ISqlServerClient SqlServerClient { get; }
    private ILogger Logger { get; }        
    public GetSampleByStatusHandler(ISqlServerClient sqlServerClient, ILogger<GetSampleByStatusHandler> logger)
    {
        SqlServerClient = sqlServerClient;
        Logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task<SampleListCriteria> Handle(GetSampleByStatusCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new SampleListCriteria();
        try 
        {
            (int totalCount, List<SampleDetails> sampleList) result = await SqlServerClient.GetSampleListByStatus(
                string.Join(",", request.SampleListCriteria.StatusIds != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.StatusIds : new int[] { }),
                request.SampleListCriteria.SampleId != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.SampleId.Value : null,
                request.SampleListCriteria.TestDate != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.TestDate.Value : null,
                1,
                "en",
                request.SampleListCriteria.Paging.PageStart, 
                request.SampleListCriteria.Paging.PageSize, 
                request.SampleListCriteria.Sorting.Field, 
                request.SampleListCriteria.Sorting.SortDirection);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
        return response;
```

I will like to return the result not the response.

Answer (score 1):

I have given two examples, the first is a working proved and tested example, and the second is what I believe you should change your code to in order to get this working. I also added some comments to your code, take it or leave it :)

**Working Example:**

```
public class TestCommand : IRequest<(int, string)>
{
    public TestCommand()
    {

    }
}

public class TestHandler : IRequestHandler<TestCommand, (int, string)>
{

    public TestHandler()
    {
    }

    public Task<(int, string)> Handle(TestCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        (int totalCount, string) result = (1, "test");

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

**Example with your code:**

```
 public class GetSampleByStatusCommand : IRequest<(int totalCount, List<SampleDetails> sampleList)>
{
    public SampleListCriteria SampleListCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class GetSampleByStatusHandler : IRequestHandler<GetSampleByStatusCommand, (int totalCount, List<SampleDetails> sampleList)>
{
    private ISqlServerClient SqlServerClient { get; }
    private ILogger Logger { get; }
    public GetSampleByStatusHandler(ISqlServerClient sqlServerClient, ILogger<GetSampleByStatusHandler> logger)
    {
        SqlServerClient = sqlServerClient;
        Logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task<(int totalCount, List<SampleDetails> sampleList)> Handle(GetSampleByStatusCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new SampleListCriteria();
        try
        {
            (int totalCount, List<SampleDetails> sampleList) result = await SqlServerClient.GetSampleListByStatus(
                string.Join(",", request.SampleListCriteria.StatusIds != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.StatusIds : new int[] { }),
                request.SampleListCriteria.SampleId != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.SampleId.Value : null,
                request.SampleListCriteria.TestDate != null ? request.SampleListCriteria.TestDate.Value : null,
                1,
                "en",
                request.SampleListCriteria.Paging.PageStart,
                request.SampleListCriteria.Paging.PageSize,
                request.SampleListCriteria.Sorting.Field,
                request.SampleListCriteria.Sorting.SortDirection);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //You should probably throw an actually exception and log the exception further down the stack.
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
        //This should probably move inside the try catch.
        return result;
    }
 }
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Happy coding!